# Google Play Game Services error: Unable to Sign in - Application does not have a registered client id? Other fixes did not work

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

Any minor information that may be relevant:

- Using C# in the Unity3d Game Engine
- App requires use of a Google obb downloader and GoogleIAB (both working correctly)
- Using the Prime31 plugins to access the following:
- Using both achievements and leaderboards (authentication issues I think?)
- App connects and posts to Facebook (working correctly)

Unable to Sign in - Application does not have a registered client id

Previously I had issues connection to Google Play Game Services. It seemed it was that my SHA1 code from my certificate fingerprint in the application was not the same as the one I had in the Game Services linked app (the default SHA1 it places there). Unfortunately I had already published, so I had to unpublish the app, unpublish the game services, and re-create them all. I used a brand new keystore that I generated (the alias name was the same though), and made sure the SHA1 code was generated from that keystore and placed into the linked app.

This worked! I tested it on device with all of my achievements and leaderboards, everything going perfectly. After a couple quick code/data changes (text updates, commenting code, etc) I rebuilt the project and uploaded the new apk and obb. Then, after publishing it, it doesn't work anymore, returning error: Unable to Sign in - Application does not have a registered client id.

This is where I found out about the Google API Console. There, I found that both my current good Client ID and the old Client ID(the one with the old keystore and wrong SHA1) were still there. Just to be safe, I deleted the old one that was no longer in use. Comparing the information in the current Client ID with the Game Services console and the keystore certificate output I saved, everything seems to be correct.

I didn't save the .keystore file within my project when I built it if that matters.
Any help is well appreciated and sorry if I put down too much information, didn't want to miss anything. Thanks!

*** EDIT 1 ***

I found a few things out and noticed another odd error during the attempt to sign in, this may be closer to the problem?:

I get this one first, right off the bat when it connects:

```
    Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {bearer=WWW-
    Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest",
    error=invalid_token}
```

Here are a couple that come in before the original error I posted:

```
    E/Volley  ( 3928): [25080] iu.a: Unexpected response code 401 for
    https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/#####################
    E/SignInIntentService( 2620): There is no linked app associated with this client ID.
    ... about 10 lines of irrelavant android output
    E/LoadSelfFragment( 2925): Unable to Sign in - Application does not have a
    registered client id
```

New Additional info I may have forgot:
I am currently in Canada signing the certificate for the company which is based in US. Could it be detecting something wrong with that? I doubt it, but just in case.

Still not solved sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you input correct the SHA1 fingerprint from you publish key
this is linked application section you really shoud have 2 keys i dev one release linked

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore <PATH_TO_YOUR_KEY_FILE> -v -list
```